# is there a method to benchmark only the filters in an ffmpeg chain, ignoring the encoder operations?

Tags: ffmpeg, benchmarking, performance-tuning

I've found a number of examples of how to use a [null muxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Null) to prevent writing the actual output to disk, which saves the disk space and all the time/work to do the writes themselves.  I'm interested in something slightly different:  I want to benchmark/compare the performance of a set of different filter chains *independent* of the encoder.  Said another way, I want to try and find a null encoder rather than a null muxer: where the output of frames from the filter chain is dumped to nowhere instead of into an encoder.

If my reference chain is:
`input -> filter1 -> filter2 -> filterN -> encoder -> muxer`

All the examples I can find show me how to do this:
`input -> filter1 -> filter2 -> filterN -> encoder -> NULL`

But what I actually want to do is **this**:
`input -> filter1 -> filter2 -> filterN -> NULL`

Comment: there is a `rawvideo` encoder which would be as close as you could expect to unencoded video data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be

```
ffmpeg -i input `bench@pre=start,filter1,filter2,filter3,bench@post=stop` -f null -
```

The first [bench filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#bench_002c-abench) starts the clock. The 2nd measures stop time and prints it per-frame, along with a cumulative average and max/min time.

Comment: Completely forgot about the bench filter. Looks like I've reached my memory limit.